# Oracle split one column data between two column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with one column with the below data

```
head1  [00100 - 00228] lab66  [lab661]
```

I have one more table with two column I need to insert the first part in one column and the second part of data in one column without []

**Table one**

```
Column1
--------------------------------------
head1  [00100 - 00228] lab66  [lab661]
```

Note: the two data is in one row

**Table two**

```
column1 | column2
head1       00100 - 00228
lab66       lab661
```

`2 column and 2 rows`

Can anyone please help me to accomplish this task

Comment: hopefully you are in the process of revamping the data model, as storing compund data in one column (as it happens in your source table) violates good db data modelling in a very fundamental way.

Comment: It's not clear whether your initial data is in one row or two. Can you clarify?

Comment: the whole data is in one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info) to accomplish the task.
try

```
 INSERT
   INTO table2 trg ( col1, col2 )
        SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(src.col1, '^([^'||chr(91)||']+)\[[^'||chr(93)||']+\].*$', '\1'))
             , LTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(src.col1, '^[^'||chr(91)||']+\[([^'||chr(93)||']+)\].*$', '\1'))
          FROM table1 src
      ;
```

explanation:

- the regex pattern describes the structure of your source column content (text + text in brackets). note that ...

  - each record's column must match this structure.
  - *the complete content* of the column is matched due to the use of `^`, `$` in the pattern.
  - `[`, `]` carry semantics in regular expressions, thus they have to be escaped to mach the literal chars. **edit** the canonical escaping (`\[`, `\]`) does not work, so you have to express the symbols using oracles `chr` funciton (remember basic ? :-)))
- the parentheses within the regex denote 'interesting' parts of the data that matches the pattern - for the first columnn, that is the text before the brackets, for the second its the part inside of them.
- the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function replaces the part of the source column matching the pattern with the replacement string. as the pattern matches the whole string, it replaces the whole string.
- the replacement string contains a so-called 'backreference' to the first 'interesting portion' of the match - which is the part corresponding to the pattern part enclosed in parentheses.
- the trim functions remove trailing/leading whitespace.

**edit:**
test script available [here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.ora.normalize.23130224.sql)

**edit #2:**
The op actually has *2* data sections to be partitioned in *1* column of the source table. This can be handled by 2 insert statements (or a union in the select of 1 statement) by upgrading the pattern for matching the 2nd item:

```
INSERT
       INTO test_tab2 trg ( col1, col2 )
            SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(src.col1, CHR(10), ' '), CHR(13), ' '), '^([^'||chr(91)||']+)\[[^'||chr(93)||']+\].*$', '\1'))
                 , LTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(src.col1, CHR(10), ' '), CHR(13), ' '), '^[^'||chr(91)||']+\[([^'||chr(93)||']+)\].*$', '\1'))
             FROM test_tab1 src
         ;
INSERT
       INTO test_tab2 trg ( col1, col2 )
            SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(src.col1, CHR(10), ' '), CHR(13), ' '), '^[^'||chr(91)||']+\[[^'||chr(93)||']+\][ ]*([^'||chr(91)||']+)\[[^'||chr(93)||']+\].*$', '\1'))
                 , LTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(src.col1, CHR(10), ' '), CHR(13), ' '), '^[^'||chr(91)||']+\[[^'||chr(93)||']+\][ ]*[^'||chr(91)||']+\[([^'||chr(93)||']+)\].*$', '\1'))
              FROM test_tab1 src
          ;
```

test script available [here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.ora.normalize.23130224.v3.sql)

**edit #3:**
the whitespace separating the 2 data sections may contain line feeds/carriage returns.
for simplified processing, added ordinary `replace` calls in select clauses.

test script available [here](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.ora.normalize.23130224.v4.sql)

Comment: it is inserting head1  [00100 - 00228]
lab66  [lab661] in one column and again head1  [00100 - 00228]
lab66  [lab661] in another column :(

Comment: this one also inserting the same value in 2 column :(

Comment: @Suman It doesn't with me (oracle 11g2). which oracle version are you testing under?

Comment: @Suman i have supplied a test script. try to run that on your system (**check for the presence of the tables `test_tab1`, `test_tab2`first, as they will be dropped !**)

Comment: head1  [00100 - 00228]
lab66  [lab661] are in one row

Comment: I am using oracle 11g

Comment: I can not ,I can not delete the data present in my database.I only want to insert the above data in another table

Comment: but as I have mentioned ,the whole head1 [00100 - 00228] lab66 [lab661] is in one row,not in two.

Comment: @Suman, sorry, after reformatting your question, this was no longer evident (cf. the comment by @Ben). will update the solution

Comment: thanks @collaper, but there is no space between ] and the next caracter the data is like head1  [00100 - 00228]lab66  [lab661]

Comment: when I checked with the script the solution is worked fine,but with my data with had a new line in row,it is not working,can you please help me for this

Comment: @Suman this does not make a difference. try the updated test script to check - it will split _2_ records according to your spec, with the second one not containing a whitespace char between the 2 components.

Comment: @Suman can handle line feeds / carriage returns now. wrt more surprises of this kind, please consider to preprocess the contents of the source table with a more appropriate tool (eg. a scriptable text editor or sed) before the segmentation.